# Getting error with mail in opencart

Tags: php, email, opencart, opencart2.x

I am working with `opencart`. I am setting `mail` on the server. I have set the details in `setting->mail` as follow

`Mail Protocol -> SMTP
SMTP Host -> tls://smtp.gmail.com
PORT -> 587`

But when I am using this then getting following error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

OK

<b>Warning</b>: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\upload\system\library\mail.php</b> on line <b>221</b><b>Notice</b>: Error: EHLO not accepted from server! in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\upload\system\library\mail.php</b> on line <b>238</b>
```

Plz help me what may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to PHP 5.6 verifies SSL certificates by default. You need to change the file class.smtp.php in line 238:

```
public function connect($host, $port = null, $timeout = 30, $options = array()) {
       if (count($options) == 0) {
           $options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);
       }
```

Here is link for [troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: This is the `opencart` here I cant find any class.smtp.php file